# Mongoose : get content of multiple subdocument in one object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hello I've been trying to select all the subdocument of multiple document returned in ONE single *object and if it's possible sorted by value.*

Here is what I mean :

My collection :

```js
    {
        userId: 1,
        ...
        items : [
            {name: "candle", value:5},
            {name: "shoes", value: 200}
        ]
    },
    {
        userId: 2,
        ...
        items : [
            {name: "burger", value:17},
            {name: "car", value: 5000}
        ]
    },
    {
        userId: 3,
        ...
        items : [
           {name: "chips", value:2},
        ]
    }
```

And I want to make a query that return me something like that :

```js
    [
    {userId:1, name: "candle", value:5},
    {userId:1, name: "shoes", value: 200},
    {userId:2, name: "burger", value:17},
    {userId:2, name: "car", value: 5000},
    {userId:3, name: "chips", value:2}
    ]
```

I've been trying this :

```js
Mymodel.find({}).select("items"); //It return me all the items but in separate object. [ {items: []} ...]
```

Also if it is possible I would like to sort them : I want to get the 3 most valuable items in the users collection. I tried to use the **aggregate** method following some example in the mongoose doc but I didn't succeed to make it work. I also have been thinking to make a new database containing only the users items so I can sort them easily but I feel like there is a better solution to do this.

So my question is do you have an idea how could I make it work ? *thank you in advance*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pasting just an option

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$unwind" : "$items"
    },
    {
        "$addFields" : {
            "name" : "$items.name",
            "value" : "$items.value"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unset" : "items"
    },
    {
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : 1,
            "value" : 1,
            "userId" : 1
        }
    }
]
```

Run `db.collname.aggregate(pipeline)` or review the syntax for the driver.

Comment: Hey sorry I put '...' because I wanted to show that document contained more than just the userId and "items" object. Sorry if it was unclear.

Thank you a lot for your answer I'll try to see how to use this!

Comment: Ok I just did it and it works prefectly. Thank you so so much. I'll try to understand how it exactly works now. I also succeded to sort the items by value by doing this : userModel.aggregate(pipeline).sort({value: -1}).limit(3).        Thank again you helped me a lot after several hours trying. Have a good day/night/life

Comment: @user14596929 ill add an email to my profile, if you have a specific question you can ask me (not to solve big problems). have a good one u2